# Concatenating instead of adding

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, string-concatenation, addition

well I'm trying to make a calculator in google scripts and whenever I try to add it concentrates rather than adding I've searched for hours any help would be greatly appreciated I have checked several forum posts and none answers my question as they have their variable already in an integer

```
function calculateNumber() {
     var calc = DocumentApp.getUi()
     var num1 = calc.prompt('Please Type First Number', calc.ButtonSet.OK)
     var one = num1.getResponseText();
     var num2 = calc.prompt('Please Type Operator', calc.ButtonSet.OK)  
     var two = num2.getResponseText()
     var num3 = calc.prompt('Please Type Second Number', calc.ButtonSet.OK)
     var three = num3.getResponseText()
     var n1 = eval(one)
     var n2 = eval(two)
     var sum = n1+n2
     if (two == '+') {
       calc.alert('Ans='+sum)

     }
   }
```

Comment: Perhaps try changing `var sum = n1+n2` to `var sum = parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2)`

Comment: Why do you use eval ? [eval is evil](https://coderwall.com/p/mkicig/eval-is-evil)

Comment: @Nick Better to use `Number`, I think

Comment: @CertainPerformance ah, why is that?

Comment: @Nick `parseInt` also accepts a radix argument, which can often cause confusion - also, `parseInt` will only transform the input to an *integer*, not just to a number (like to `0.2`) - if all you want to do is coerce, probably best to just use `Number`

Comment: Add more details like a sample input values and the expected results.(maybe you are using comma as decimal separator )

Comment: @CertainPerformance oh alright, awesome. Thanks. I think since early on the radix argument has been a non factor. I remember at some point it was base 2 or something. But yeah the decimal piece is certainly a great reason.

Answer (score 0):

`n1` and `n2` are strings, you need to cast them to integers, use `parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2`);

Comment: It responds with NaN

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
function calculateNumber() {
     var calc = DocumentApp.getUi()
     var num1 = calc.prompt('Please Type First Number', calc.ButtonSet.OK)
     var one = num1.getResponseText();
     var num2 = calc.prompt('Please Type Operator', calc.ButtonSet.OK)  
     var two = num2.getResponseText()
     var num3 = calc.prompt('Please Type Second Number', calc.ButtonSet.OK)
     var three = num3.getResponseText()
     if (two === '+') {
       var sum = Number(one)+Number(three);
       calc.alert('Ans='+sum)

     }
   }
```

Comment: responds with nan

Comment: I don't quite get why you have the 'if (two == '+')...' segment. If you just remove it, and print the result directly using ' calc.alert('Ans='+sum)' it should show numbers

Comment: its a four function calculator thats to check its operator

Comment: im checking it though

Comment: Replies with nan

Comment: I've updated the code - try again please.